# Unbound Prefix in layout XML in com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView when try to add "map:...." attribute

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a MapView (com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView, NOT using support) inside a LLayout. 
The MapView works perfectly fine, meaning I can see the map, I can zoom in and out. 
BUT
when I try to add any of map:... attributes the compiler gives the error: unbound prefix.

I have google_play_services lib added to my project. 
My manifest has every necessary item added according to developers guide.

What am I missing? I Googled a lot but nothing worked for me.

Here is my fragment_map.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        map:cameraTargetLat="-33.123456"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<permission 
    android:name="com.***.***.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature">
</permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.***.***.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.***.***.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.***.***.ActivitySearchPropertyListing"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_search_property_listing" >
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCbMZNV8ylf0J3m16l6tUHJJLHP7EhTmRI"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

My project Libraries and build path:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map):

> In order to use these custom attributes within your XML layout file, you must first add the following namespace declaration (you can choose any namespace, it doesn't have to be `map`):

```
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

> You can then add the attributes with a `map:` prefix into your layout components, as you would with standard Android attributes.

You do not have this namespace declaration on your `LinearLayout`.